# config/Environment is missing on redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I have upgrade my rails version to 3.0 and I got the following error message

```
no such file to load -- path_to_application/config/environment
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Rails 3 support is at best beta: http://www.redmine.org/issues/4796

It looks like Rails 3.0 is not supported:

> Redmine will never run with 3.0 due to the lack of engine support.

From the above linked issue, the developers seem to be targeting Rails 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the Rails 3 you have installed override Redmine's Rails 2.3.

One simple way to fix that is to add Bundler to your Redmine installation, which will put it into an isolated set of gems.

See [Using Bundler with Rails 2.3](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html).

Comment: For clarification, you will **not** make Redmine work with Rails 3. You have to isolate it with Bundler.